# Как найти ключевые слова в тексте одного столбца DataFrame?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, pandas, numpy, csv

у меня есть файл CSV я его прочитал, импортировал библиотеки
мне необходимо найти ключевые слова в тексте одного столбца:

вот эти критерии, отдельно:

```
/city/directory/<цифры или буквы>.html

/good/<цифры>/owner_info

/bulletin/<цифры>
```

и пользователь у которого совпадали эти 3 критерии совместно

мой код

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

exp = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\4X\Desktop\pandas\study\...csv')

re.findall('(?:/good/)|(?:/owner_info)', '/good/<цифры>/owner_info?')
exp.query('url == @card_filte')
```

здесь все отрабатывает

а вот со вторым и третьим не работает

```
contacs1 = re.findall(r'(?:/good/)|(?:/owner_info)', '/good/<цифры>/owner_info?')
exp.query('url == @contacs1_filte')

contacs2 = re.findall(r'(?:/bulletin/)', '/bulletin/<цифры>')
exp.query('url == @contacs1_filte')
```

Comment: можете привести небольшой пример входных данных и то, что ожидаете получить на выходе?

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Название столбцов  user_id, date, url  мне нужно вывести количество пользователей  у которых: в столбце url совпадает текст /city/directory/<цифры или буквы>.html

/good/<цифры>/owner_info

/bulletin/<цифры>

Comment: воспользуйтесь кнопкой ["править"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1020904/edit) под вопросом чтобы привести в вопросе примеры данных...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для того чтобы искать в столбце используя регулярные выражения можно воспользоваться [pandas.Series.str.contains()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
mask = df["column_name"].str.contains(r"<reg_exp>")
res = df.loc[mask]
```

PS если в вопросе будет приведен пример данных и ожидаемый результат, то я дополню вопрос примером, с использованием ваших данных...

Comment: Огромное спасибо !!!!! ;)  все работает )))) ура  !!!!! всего наилучшего тебе ;)

Answer (score 0):

хотел бы добавить для дополнительных знаний способы посчитать не только ключевые слова, но и биграммы и триграммы разными способами

```
# импорт библиотек 
from nltk import ngrams
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import Counter
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import re

#визуализируем самые частые слова
word_counter = ' '.join(data['Textl'].tolist()).split()
word_counter = pd.DataFrame(Counter(word_counter).most_common(20))
word_counter.columns = ['word','cnt']
plt.figure(figsize=(17, 6))
sns.barplot(data=word_counter,y='word',x='cnt');
```

Через модуль ngrams из nltk

```
# Функция для извлечения ключевых слов, биграмм и триграмм
def extract_ngrams(tokens):
    keywords = tokens
    bigrams = list(ngrams(tokens, 2))
    trigrams = list(ngrams(tokens, 3))
    # Преобразование биграмм и триграмм в строки
    bigrams = [' '.join(bigram) for bigram in bigrams]
    trigrams = [' '.join(trigram) for trigram in trigrams]
    return keywords, bigrams, trigrams
```

Применяем функцию к столбцу с токенизированным текстом

```
data['Keywords'], data['Bigrams'], data['Trigrams'] =
    zip(*data['Text'].apply(lambda x: extract_ngrams(x) if x else ([], [], [])))
```

Через каунтвекторайзер на примере биграмм, но как видно это можно делать и с униграммами и с триграммами идентичным образом.

```
vec = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2,2))
X = vec.fit_transform(new_df['Text_lem'])
sum_words = X.sum(axis=0)
bigram_freq = [(word, sum_words[0, idx]) for word, idx in vec.vocabulary_.items()]
bigram_freq = pd.DataFrame(bigram_freq)
bigram_freq.columns = ['bigram','cnt']
bigram_freq = bigram_freq.sort_values(by='cnt', ascending=False)

for word in bigram_freq.iloc[:10]['bigram'].values:
    data[f'bigram_{word}'] = data['Textl'].str.contains(word).astype(int)

cols = [col for col in new_df.columns if 'unigram' in col or 'bigram' in col or 'trigram' in col]
data[['Textl'] + cols]
```

и еще один способ через nltk

```
data['trigrams3'] = data['Texttl'].apply(lambda row: list(nltk.trigrams(row)))
data['trigrams3'].head(10)
```